# This annotation is not allowed at this location (@Valid)

Tags: spring-boot, validation, spring-validator, spring-validation

I am trying to validate the list which is passed as a parameter to a controller in spring-boot application.
I referred Baeldung doc to perform the same, below is the code snippet which i tried to implement

```
@PostMapping
public void addAll(@RequestBody @NotEmpty(message = "Input movie list cannot be empty.") List<@Valid Movie> movies) {
    movieService.addAll(movies);
}
```

but it throws an error saying "@Valid annotation is not allowed in this location" (this is compile time error, i haven't executed the code hence there is no stacktrace)

Suggest a fix for the same

I did the same thing as shown in the image

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: There is far too little information in this question to answer it. Please provide code and the actual **full stacktrace** you get.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the @Valid annotaion is in front of the List and not the generic list type.
Also make sure your Movie class implements @Valid validations.

Comment: i actually wanted to validate each object inside the list, and all the required validators are added in Movie class

Comment: make sure you imported the correct @Valid annotation class. Maybe also have a look at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-validate-list-controller

Comment: yeah I validated the imports, they are correctly imported and i was referring to the same doc